# conditionally assign value to variable doesn't work

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am new in shell scripting. I have written a simple script to assign variable conditionally:

```
#!/bin/sh

my_env=$1

if (my_env=="dev"); then
  MY_TYPE="dev type"
elif (my_env=="stg"); then
  MY_TYPE="stg type"
elif (my_env=="prod"); then
  MY_TYPE="prod type"
fi
echo $MY_TYPE
```

When I run it:

```
$shell ./my_script.sh dev
```

It prints out: `dev type`, which is correct.

after that, I run again with :

```
$shell ./my_script.sh stg
```

It also print out `dev type`. Why it doesn't print out `stg type`?? Where is wrong in my conditional logic?

Comment: When you write `$shell ./my_script.sh stg` which bit is the command you're actually running?

Comment: "man csh", please! See "Variable substitution".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sh` language is not the `C` language, you can't just expect one thing that works in one language will work in another language.

`sh` is before all a command line interpreter. Most things are done by commands which the shell is there to invoke.

For instance, to evaluate conditional tests, there's a dedicated command for that: `[` aka `test`. The `if`/`then`/`fi` is a syntax structure of `sh`, but its action is based on the success or failure of the command list that is in-between `if` and `then`.

For the contents of a variable to be passed to a command, you need the `$var` syntax. `echo foo` passes `foo` to the `echo` command, `echo "$foo"` passes the contents of the `$foo` variable to `echo` (note the quotes which are important (even [critical in the case of the `[` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22565)) in `sh` to work around an unfortunate misfeature).

In `sh`, `(...)` is to run a subshell, for the code within to be interpreted in a separate environment (in most `sh` implementations, in a child process), and `my_env=="dev"` is just the same as `my_env="=dev"`¹ which assigns `=dev` to the `$my_env` variable, which it will succeed to do, so the subshell will also be successful, so the `then` part will be run.

The correct syntax would be:

```
#!/bin/sh -

my_env="$1"

if [ "$my_env" = dev ]; then
  MY_TYPE="dev type"
elif [ "$my_env" = stg ]; then
  MY_TYPE="stg type"
elif [ "$my_env" = prod ]; then
  MY_TYPE="prod type"
fi
printf '%s\n' "$MY_TYPE"
```

Though here, you'd rather use a `case` construct (similar to `C`'s `switch`):

```
#! /bin/sh -
my_env=${1?Missing type argument}

case $my_env in
  (dev | stg | prod)
    MY_TYPE="$my_env type"
    ;;
  (*)
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "Unsupported type: $my_env"
    exit 1
esac

printf 'MY_TYPE = %s\n' "$MY_TYPE"
```

See also the catch-all that exits with a failure exit status if `$my_env` is not among an allowed set to avoid `$MY_TYPE` be used uninitialised below, and the `${1?error}` as a quick way to ensure the script is passed at least one argument and report an error to the user if not.

---

<sup>¹ or `my_env='=dev'` or `my_env==dev` or `my_env='='"d"e\v`, but not `my_env'==dev'` nor `$my_dev==dev`, the important part being that the first `=` be literal and unquoted and what's left of it be literal, unquoted and a valid variable name for it to be taken as a variable assignment command. `my_env'==dev'` would try and run a command called `my_env==dev` (and likely fail to find it)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, since I am new in shell,  just out of my curiosity, is bash script more favoured/recommended than shell ?  I am now converting my script to bash, so, could you please help providing a counter-part bash script since my script is very simple. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user842225, `bash` supports the `sh` language syntax, even more closely when it's itself invoked as `sh` so this code will work in `bash` as well. I'm not a big fan of `bash` myself, as it has copied most of the misfeature of `ksh`. For shells with some *improvements* over the POSIX `sh` syntax, you can have a look at shells like `rc`, `zsh` or `fish` (among which `zsh` is the most `sh`-like).

Comment: Thanks.  I try to capitalize all letters from input, I tried `my_env=${1^^?Missing type argument}`. but end up with error `line 2: ${1^^?Missing type argument}: bad substitution`, could you please help on this?  I see people using `^^` to capitalize all letters, why not working with my syntax?

Comment: `${var^^}` is bash syntax, not sh syntax. See also `$var:u` or `${(U)var}` in zsh. But bash (contrary to zsh) has very limited support for combining parameter expansion operators, so you'd need to do it in two steps there. The specification of the `sh` language can be found [there](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18).

Comment: How can I wrap it in a function and call the function in the same shell script file?